# Azure AD Premium On Premises Password Reset with ADFS

Tags: microsoft-office-365, adfs, entra-id

We are evaluating the Self-Service Password Reset/Change/Unlock with on-premises writeback feature of Azure AD Premium in our O365 Tenant. 
Considering that we have implemented the Authentication through ADFS can we implement the Self-Service Password Reset?

Answer (score 0):

The cloud self-service is independent of ADFS, so can be used instead of, or with it.

**Edit**
Just so it's clear.  The answer is yes you can use it with ADFS.

Comment: It can be used instead of ADFS but only if you manage your users independently or only use password sync. If you want Single Sign On in the corporate network you have to use ADFS and connect Azure AD with it.

Comment: True but your question made no mention of SSO.

Comment: That's because SSO is not part of the question, I was just explaining why we use ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS provides a federation layer on top of AD.

The password reset is AD functionality not ADFS so there are no issues.

Comment: Actually ADFS is a federation layer on top of AD BUT the SelfService Password Reset is a feature of AAD (Azure Active Directory). AAD and On-Premises are connected through the Azure AD Connect tool

Comment: Agreed, AAD Connect doesn't use ADFS.

Comment: ADFS does have a password change function (you have to know your password), though not reset.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's why I said "Self-Service Password Reset/Change/Unlock" in my original question.